# Open and close side menu with same button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I use one button to display a side menu and another to close it

```
<script>
$('#open-menu').click(function() {
  $("#mySidenav").css("width" , "250px");
  $("#l_m").css({"marginLeft": "250px", "position" : "absolute", "width" : "100%"});
  // $(this).attr('id','close-menu');
});

$('#close-menu').click(function() {
  $("#mySidenav").css("width" , "0");
  $("#l_m").css("marginLeft" , "0");
});
</script>
```

But I want the same button opens and closes my menu
How to do ? Knowing that I use Jquery 1.11.3

Thank you

(I tried to add the line that is commented but when I click on it, nothing happens)

Comment: Please include all relevant code.

Comment: If you use the same button you can use a custom toggle using a property (`$(/**/).prop`)

Comment: I have edit my post and add the CSS

Answer (score 2):

Move the open styles into separate css classes. Then toggle these classes on button click using the jQuery [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function.

**Javascript:**

```
$('#toggle-menu').click(function() {
  $("#mySidenav").toggleClass("open");
  $("#l_m").toggleClass("open");
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#mySidenav {
  width: 0;
}

#mySidenav.open {
  width: 250px;
}

#l_m {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#l_m.open {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 250px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make a class to show the menu and toggle this class on button click...!

```js
$('#open-menu').click(function() {
  $("#mySidenav").toggleClass('show')
});
```

```css
#mySidenav {background: red; height: 100px; display: none;}
.show {display: block !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mySidenav"></div>
<button id="open-menu">Menu</button>
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want use another jquery version

Comment: The version of jquery used in the snippet is irrelevant here - it's just using `.toggleClass` which has been around since 1.0 http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/  I've updated the code to show it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do, I call this "trick" a custom toggle :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(/*selector for the button*/)
    .click(function(){
      const $this = $(this);
      let prop = $this.prop("opened");

      if(prop === undefined){
        $this.prop("opened", false);
        prop = $this.prop("opened");
      }

      if(prop === false){
        /*handle opening here*/
      }

      if(prop === true){
        /*handle closing here*/
      }

      $this.prop("opened", !prop);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what `$().data()` is for (rather than `.prop`) (but otherwise a sound idea)

Comment: Yeah data works fine too, but unlike prop it ends up on the html ;)

Comment: I suspect you have the two mixed up - `.data()` does not change the html.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this simple approach using jQuery data attribute.

```
<a id="menu" data-stat="close">Menu Button</a>

$('#menu').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).data('stat') == "close"){
        $(this).data('stat', 'open');

        /* open Menu code */

    }else if($(this).data('stat') == "open"){
        $(this).data('stat', 'close');

        /* close Menu code */

    }
});
```